# how to make this bridge to work?

Tags: linux-networking, bridge

I have posted a similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873819/customising-docker-network-doesnt-work#

To simplify the question, let me get rid of docker.

This is the network model:

```
          | CentOS
gateway --|-- enp0s9----br0----A---B
10.0.0.1  |                        10.0.1.100
```

CentOS is a VM, `enp0s9` is a the VM's NIC. `br0` is a linux bridge, `A` is a veth interface, `B` is `A`'s peer.

I configure them with the following commands:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl stp br0 off
brctl addif enp0s9
ip link add A type veth peer name B
brctl addif br0 A
ip link set dev A up
ip addr add 10.0.1.100/24 dev B
ip link set dev B up
```

After this configure:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:22:dd:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:79:04:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:38:f0:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT
    link/ether 08:00:27:38:f0:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: B: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:66:81:1c:ca:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: A: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:f8:de:9d:b3:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

But when I ping gateway from the CentOS, using tcpdump, I can see the gateway has heard ARP Request and replied ARP Reply. But enp0s9 hears only ARP Request but ARP Reply.

On gateway:

```
22:54:15.386328 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.1 tell 10.0.1.100, length 46
22:54:15.386350 ARP, Reply 10.0.1.1 is-at 0a:00:27:00:00:01 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

On enp0s9:

```
09:54:58.748210 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.1 tell localhost.localdomain, length 28
```

What problem is with my configure? How can make gateway and B to ping each other?

In this configure, `enp0s9` acts as L2 hub, is there any special configure should be done on it?

Answer (score 0):

Docker networking as it stands right now is not exactly simple to get right. I would recommend trying [weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave/blob/master/README.md#weave---the-docker-network).

Comment: _Disclaimer: I am part of the Weaveworks, Inc. team._